# strange red icon up left in Oracle MAF 2.5.1 default applications

Tags: oracle-maf

[image]

Does somebody knows why appear this icon  to all my new applications in M.A.F 2.5.1 Jdeveloper 12.1.3
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I Found it!
https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/maf/2.5.1/develop/deploying-maf-applications.html#GUID-8806E3F2-5CDF-4FB0-9EC5-24C36E023A13

For deployment to device or emulator options, MAF installs and launches the MAF application. If you deployed the MAF application in debug mode, a red icon appears on each screen of the MAF application, as shown in the upper-left portion of the figure. MAF applications that you deploy in release mode do not render this icon.